# Non RFC-compliant URI schemes

Tags: .net, uri, url-scheme

In my .NET 4.5 application, I would like to provide support for a bunch of **wildly** unconventional URI schemes (as defined in [this](http://dune-hd.com/firmware/misc/media_url.txt) draft).

**URI schemes with double scheme identifiers**

```
www://http://www.example.com/

http://ts://www.example.com/

http://mp4://www.example.com/
```

**URI schemes with illegal characters** (underscores)

```
network_folder://path/

storage_name://path/

storage_label://path/
```

I was hoping to extend `System.Uri` in a way that it would recognize URIs like the ones above, but there just doesn't seem to be a way to make it accept these crazy inputs. I tried extending `System.GenericUriParser` in order to implement my own parsing logic, but even that won't let me use non RFC-compliant schemes.

I would really like to avoid exposing these URIs as string objects, but at this point I'm just completely lost. Besides trying to kick some sense into the developer who came up with these schemes, is there anything else in the framework that I can use to set things right?

Comment: Are you trying to store these in a System.Uri or Uri-derived object?

Comment: Have you tried System.UriBuilder?

Comment: @PeterRitchie I've tried doing both, but it simply doesn't allow overriding the scheme with a string that contains illegal characters.

Comment: The closest I've got is extending `System.Uri`, then overriding `ToString()` so it would have the custom scheme in it.

Comment: I think that's about the best you can do.  Uri simply doesn't support invalidate schemes.

Comment: I think I'd rather just pass them around as string objects then :/